# Print text file as two separate lists

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, text-files

I am new to Python and stackoverflow :). I have a txt file which I need to print from. This is the txt file called DOB and has the following info:

```
Orville Wright 21 July 1988   
Rogelio Holloway 13 September 1988  
Marjorie Figueroa 9 October 1988  
Debra Garner 7 February 1988
```

I need to print and display the list like this:

```
 1. Orville Wright  
 2. Regelio Holloway  
 3. ......
```

list item

```
 1. 21 July 1988
 2. 13 September 1988
 3. .......
```

My code below opens the txt file twice and I don't think that is effective. Help!

```
dob = open('DOB.txt', 'r')

for i, line in enumerate(dob, 1):
    name = line.split()                                              
    name_surname = str(i) + "." + " " + name[0] + " " + name[1]      
    print(name_surname)

dob = open('DOB.txt', 'r')

for i, line in enumerate(dob, 1):  
    date = line.split()  
    day_to_year = str(i) + "." + " " + date[2] + " " + date[3] + " " + date[4]  

    print(day_to_year)  
dob.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling read() reads through the entire file and leaves the read cursor at the end of the file (with nothing more to read).

Once a file has been read, with read() you can use seek(0) to return the read cursor to the start of the file (docs are [here](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/bltin-file-objects.html)). No need to open the file twice.

Use [file.seek](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) to jump to a specific position in a file. However, think about whether it is really necessary to go through the file again. Maybe there is a better option.

There can be another way of solving this problem, which is read the data once, have it saved in proper lists/variables and use it as you want. For example print it out in the format way you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

file = "/Users/rprakash/python/records.txt"

data = open(file, 'r')

for i, line in enumerate(data, 1):
    details = line.split()
    name = details[0] + " " + details[1]
    print str(i) + ". " + name

data.seek(0)

for i, line in enumerate(data, 1):
    details = line.split()
    dob = details[2] + " " + details[3] + " " + details[4]
    print str(i) + ". " + dob
```

Output:

```
1. Orville Wright
2. Rogelio Holloway
3. Marjorie Figueroa
4. Debra Garner
1. 21 July 1988
2. 13 September 1988
3. 9 October 1988
4. 7 February 1988
```

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: How does accepting an answer work? [for more information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)